# Do i need a 365 subscription to send an email?

Tags: office365, exchange-server

I have a client that is using office 365 that would like a contact form on their website which once submitted, sends an email to themself. They have 2 email accounts XYZ@zzz.com & info@zzz.com, they have an exchange plan subscription on XYZ@zzz.com and no subscription on info@.

To use info@ as a relay to send internal emails to XYZ@, would they need a subscription?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XYZ@ has SendAs permissions for info@, you should be able to send e-mails on behalf of this mailbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?view=o365-worldwide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365

A more simple solution would be to use the local SMTP server of the server where the website is hosted, a SMTP available from the provider offering the webhosting or simply buy access to a SMTP-server somewhere else.

Remember to adjust SPF-records in DNS to allow the particular SMTP-server to send emails on behalf of the domain.